# Why my client.go cannot access math.go?

Tags: go

1. Why is my `math.go` file not found in `client.go` ?
2. Is `package main` the right package for `client.go` ? If I do `package bar` it complaints.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't use relative imports. Set up your workspace according to the documentation at [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: That link helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of importing ../foo/math you want to import ../foo because you're importing the folder aka the package. There is no folder named math.

If you import ../foo you can use the exported features of all the files within that folder.

As for part two of your question, there needs to be a package main if you are producing an executable, usually I keep my main go file in the root directory instead in a folder. If you are simply making a library than instead of main the package name is the name of the folder (package) as per usual.

If you have a lot of folders no one will be able to find the main function if it's in a folder called bar.

Comment: This is only a temporary solution, since you cannot use relative import paths inside of GOPATH..

Comment: There only needs to be a package main if you're producing an executable. If you're just publishing a library, you don't need a package main.

Comment: @Adrian, that's true, I didn't consider he might be making a library. I will update my answer accordingly.